# Query To update two tables at same time

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am trying to update two columns at same time, i wrote a query but its not working

```
UPDATE tbl1, 
tbl2
SET tbl1.Qty =10
tbl2.Qty = 10
FROM tbl1
INNER JOIN tbl2
ON tbl1.Id =tbl2.Id
```

Comment: No, you cant do this way & your title & body text not matching.

Answer (score 3):

A SQL Server `update` statement does not allow updating more than one table at a time.  You have several options.  Three that come to mind:

1. You can update *one* table and create an `update` trigger on that table to update a second table.
2. You can create a view of the two tables and update the *view*.  This requires an `update` trigger on the view.
3. You can write a stored procedure to do the two updates within a single transaction.